# How to regain access on not responding server due to systemd service

Tags: ssh, vps

Since I started Loki and Promtail on my Ubuntu VPS, the server is not responding any more. I assume Promtail is causing a 100% CPU load. It is run via systemd with `restart=on-failure` setting. SSH is not responding. I want to stop the service, just don't know how, because the server is not responding. Any tip how to solve this checkmate situation?

Comment: Login via web console of AWS

Comment: Check if your hosting provider has any support for web console or VNC connection. Alternatively, reboot your server in rescue and check your SSH firewall. You can scan for open ports using `nmap <IP>` on your PC

Comment: It was company internal, I have no idea how they are running the VPS. I created an internal ticket, they solved it with a hard reset. My assumption about the CPU was correct.

Comment: If you need these 2 server, start by them using nice to lower their priorities. So you still connect and use the system even if they use 100% CPU